# Vagrant synced folder permissions with `app/console`

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

In my `Vagrantfile` I have described a synced folder with liberal permissions as per the docs and [sample box](https://box.scotch.io/):

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

When I'm using the VM via `vagrant ssh`, any `app/console` attempt will return permission denied. Checking the entry on the VM, sure enough, the file is not executable:

`-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   867 Nov 13 12:11 console`

However on the host I can see the file has correct permissions (OS X):

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 chris  staff    867 13 Nov 12:11 console`

I presume the `fmode=666` is stripping the executable bit.

*If I change that, won't it set everything executable? Is there a way to mirror per-file permissions from the host while still changing the owner/group?*

Answer (score 0):

The value for file permissions are as following

- 4 read (r)
- 2 write (w)
- 1 execute (x)

so 6 corresponds to 4+2 (read + write) which is what you see so its consistent.

If you want to match your OS permission (`rwxr-xr-x`) you would need to set `755` as file mode

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=755"]
```

Comment: Thanks Frédéric. I'm worried applying blanket permissions to all project files will cause other problems? Re-worded the question to clarify.. can I ask it to mirror each file's permissions on the host?

Comment: yes, in this case you do not even need the `mount_options` by default vagrant will make same file permission on VM than you have on your host - you specifically use the `mount_options` if you want to change those permissions